# Universal formula for direction angle of a vector for any quadrant

Tags: vectors, angle

I was studying how to find the angle between the (positive) $X$-axis and a position vector for a program I'm making. And I came to the conclusion that there is no universal formula for that. If I use the following formula: $$\theta = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac yx\right)$$ I have to add a particular offset depending on the quadrant where the vector is.

So I was wondering if there was another formula, another way to think about this problem, where the formula wouldn't have to change depending on the quadrant. It would be the universal formula for finding the angle. Google search didn't do any good.

Also is there a universal formula (in the sense mentioned above) for finding the angle between any two position vectors without having to offset the angle in any way?

I'm sorry for my bad English and my poor knowledge in Mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are clearly seeking for [the two-argument inverse tangent function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) $\left(x,y\right)\mapsto\arctan\left(x,y\right)$.

Its main difference from the plain old $\tan^{-1}$ is *precisely* that it takes the quadrant of the point $\left(x,y\right)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ into account, which is lost when the usual one-argument arctangent function version is used like you first intended due to the identities $$\frac xy=\frac{-x}{-y}$$ and $$\frac{-x}y=\frac x{-y}$$ which arise when the usual one-argument inverse tangent function is used like follows: $$\arctan\left(x/y\right).$$

To mitigate the problem, instead use the two-argument version $\arctan\left(x,y\right)$, which in most languages is known as `arctan2`, `atan2` or something similar.

Comment: Thank you @dbanet Is there any way to universalize this function like the one above, because it seems that this function depends on the quadrant too: cos(theta)= dotProduct(a, b) / ||a||  * ||b|| (to find angle between to vectors a,b)?

Comment: Excuse me @user3071028, I'm not following how does the angle between vectors depend on their position relative to the basis. Which function are you trying to build?

Comment: I don't know how to explain this, but I used this function to calculate angle between some unit vector(that represented direction of a line) and (1, 0) in order to rotate text to have the same rotation as the line. And when testing, the text was rotated correctly only for lines that pointed in certain range of directions, and for the others i had to add offset to the angle to get the right angle. So that made me think that this had something to do with the quadrant the vectors are in. Sorry if this makes no sense.

Comment: @user3071028 $(1,0)$ is the unit vector on the $x$ axis. So if there is some other vector $(a,b)$ and you need to know the angle $\theta$ such that the vector $(1,0)$, when rotated by $\theta$ in positive (anticlockwise) direction, lands on the direction of $(a,b)$, then $\theta$ is just the angle between the positive direction of $x$ axis and $(a,b)$. Hence, use $\theta=\arctan(b,a)$.

Comment: A word of warning about how to read this answer: most people use $x$ as the coordinate in the direction of the $x$ axis, so that the vector with $x=1$ and $y=0$ should have angle $0$ with the $x$ axis. In most implementations, `atan2(1,0)` will produce $\frac\pi2,$ a right angle. To get the angle with the $x$ axis, in most implementations you give the $y$ coordinate first and the $x$ coordinate second; `atan2(0,1)` produces the value $0,$ as desired. I usually document this as: the angle is `atan2(y,x)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many, but here is one.

If $x=y=0$ then $\theta$ is undefined.

Then

\begin{equation}
\theta=\begin{cases}
       \frac{y}{|y|}\arccos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)\text{ if }y\ne 0\\
       \frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{x}{|x|}-1\right)\text{ if }x\ne0\text{ and }y=0
       \end{cases}
\end{equation}

This will give a result $-\pi<\theta\le \pi$.

Answer (score 0):

A formula for the angle of a vector from 0 to 2pi.

f(x,y)=pi()-pi()/2*(1+sign(x))*(1-sign(y^2))

```
     -pi()/4*(2+sign(x))*sign(y)

     -sgn(x*y)*atan((abs(x)-abs(y))/(abs(x)+abs(y)))
```

The formula gives the angle for any value of x and y.

For x=y=0 the result is undefined.